# Finding Maximum Value (Related To Least Common Multiple)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $l(x,y)$ be the least common multiple of two natural numbers $x$ and $y$.
Assume that $1<a<b<c<d$ and $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ are natural numbers.

Find the maximum value of $~\dfrac{1}{l(a,b)}+\dfrac{1}{l(a,c)}+\dfrac{1}{l(a,d)}+\dfrac{1}{l(b,c)}+\dfrac{1}{l(b,d)}+\dfrac{1}{l(c,d)}$.

Comment: I suspect the maximum will be obtained for $2,3,4,6$, giving $\frac{11}{12}$.